# Calculate ideal font size, based on the paper size and maximum allowed text length

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, gdi+, gdi

I have printing code that draws grid on the paper.

Grid has 4 columns, and they have equal horizontal length. Height of the cell is tenth of the paper size. Total number of rows is unknown but I know for a fact that there will be at least one row.

Each cell has same physical size-> width is quarter of the paper width, and height is one tenth of the paper height. **Maximum number of characters that can fit into cell is 50.**

The problem I face is choosing proper font size so text of maximum length can fit into cell.

Browsing through *MSDN* documentation and `WinAPI` examples, I saw that they use `GetTextExtPoint32` for similar purposes, but this works only **if font already exists and is selected into device context**, which is not the case here.

The only thing that crossed my mind was to create "dummy font", see if the example text can fit into cell, and then adjust it's size if the test fails. I have also found [this blog](http://www.pearsonified.com/2011/12/golden-ratio-typography.php) that recommends interesting approach to this problem, but being inexperienced I can't decide if "this is the proper way to go".

Can you recommend a correct solution for my problem?

### EDITED on June, 30th 2014:

Below is the sample function that draws grid and paints upper left cell in light gray since that cell will contain sample text. That way we can visually validate the success of our drawing code:

```
// hWnd is the window that owns the property sheet.
HRESULT GDI_PRINT(HWND hWnd)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};
    LPPRINTPAGERANGE pPageRanges = NULL;

    // Allocate an array of PRINTPAGERANGE structures.
    pPageRanges = (LPPRINTPAGERANGE) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 10 * sizeof(PRINTPAGERANGE));

    if (!pPageRanges)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    //  Initialize the PRINTDLGEX structure.
    pdx.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
    pdx.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    pdx.hDevMode = NULL;
    pdx.hDevNames = NULL;
    pdx.hDC = NULL;
    pdx.Flags = PD_RETURNDC;
    pdx.Flags2 = 0;
    pdx.ExclusionFlags = 0;
    pdx.nPageRanges = 0;
    pdx.nMaxPageRanges = 10;
    pdx.lpPageRanges = pPageRanges;
    pdx.nMinPage = 1;
    pdx.nMaxPage = 1000;
    pdx.nCopies = 1;
    pdx.hInstance = 0;
    pdx.lpPrintTemplateName = NULL;
    pdx.lpCallback = NULL;
    pdx.nPropertyPages = 0;
    pdx.lphPropertyPages = NULL;
    pdx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;
    pdx.dwResultAction = 0;

    //  Invoke the Print property sheet.

    hResult = PrintDlgEx(&pdx);

    if ( ( hResult == S_OK ) && ( pdx.dwResultAction == PD_RESULT_PRINT ) )
    {

        // User clicked the Print button, 
        // so use the DC and other information returned in the 
        // PRINTDLGEX structure to print the document.

        //======= Various initializations ==========//

        DOCINFO diDocInfo = {0};
        diDocInfo.cbSize = sizeof( DOCINFO ); 
        diDocInfo.lpszDocName = L"Testing printing...";

        int pageWidth = GetDeviceCaps( pdx.hDC, HORZRES ), 
            pageHeight = GetDeviceCaps( pdx.hDC, VERTRES ); 

        //===================== IMPORTANT !!! ==========================//
        //               Must test this on real printer !!!             //
        //         For now testing is done in XPS and MS OneNote2007    //
        //==============================================================//

        //================== end of initialization =====================//

        if( StartDoc( pdx.hDC, &diDocInfo ) > 0 )
        {
            if( StartPage( pdx.hDC ) > 0 )
            {
                //===== creating red pen that will draw grid =====//
                LOGBRUSH lb;
                lb.lbColor = RGB( 255, 0, 0 );
                lb.lbHatch = 0;
                lb.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;

                HPEN hPen = ExtCreatePen( PS_COSMETIC | PS_SOLID, 1, &lb, 0, NULL); 
                HGDIOBJ oldPen = SelectObject( pdx.hDC, hPen );

                // create test font
                HFONT font, oldFont; 

                long lfHeight = -MulDiv( 14,
                    GetDeviceCaps( pdx.hDC, LOGPIXELSY ), 
                    72 );

                font = CreateFont( lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, 
                    FW_BOLD, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                    0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, L"Microsoft Sans Serif" );

                oldFont = SelectFont( pdx.hDC, font );

                SetBkMode( pdx.hDC, TRANSPARENT );
                SetTextColor( pdx.hDC, RGB( 255, 0, 0 ) );

                // testing rectangle -> top left cell of the grid
                RECT rcText;

                rcText.left = 0;
                rcText.top = 0;
                rcText.right = pageWidth / 4;
                rcText.bottom = pageHeight / 10;

                // fill destination rectangle with gray brush
                // so we can visually validate rectangle coordinates 
                FillRect( pdx.hDC, &rcText, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH) );

                // implement solution mentioned in the comment to this question
                SIZE s;
                ::GetTextExtentPoint32( pdx.hDC, 
                    L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги", 
                    wcslen( L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги" ), 
                    &s );

                // select old font back and dispose test font
                SelectObject( pdx.hDC, oldFont );
                DeleteObject( font );

                // adjust font height
                lfHeight *= s.cy / ( rcText.bottom - rcText.top );

                // now we can create proper font 
                font = CreateFont( lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, 
                    FW_BOLD, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                    0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, L"Microsoft Sans Serif" );

                oldFont = SelectFont( pdx.hDC, font );

                // draw text in test rectangle 
                DrawTextEx( pdx.hDC,
                    L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги", 
                    wcslen( L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги" ), 
                    &rcText, DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOCLIP, NULL );

                //============== draw a testing grid ===============//

                // draw vertical lines of the grid
                for( int i = 0; i <= pageWidth; i += pageWidth / 4 )
                {
                    MoveToEx( pdx.hDC, i, 0, NULL );
                    LineTo( pdx.hDC, i, pageHeight );
                }

                // draw horizontal lines of the grid
                for( int j = 0; j <= pageHeight; j += pageHeight / 10 )
                {
                    MoveToEx( pdx.hDC, 0, j, NULL );
                    LineTo( pdx.hDC, pageWidth, j );
                }

                // no need for pen anymore so delete it
                SelectObject( pdx.hDC, oldPen );
                DeleteObject( hPen );

                // no need for font, delete it
                SelectFont( pdx.hDC, oldFont );
                DeleteFont( font );

                if( EndPage( pdx.hDC ) < 0 )
                // for now pop a message box saying something went wrong
                    MessageBox( hWnd, L"EndDoc failed!", L"Error", MB_OK );
            }

            EndDoc( pdx.hDC );
        }
    }

    if (pdx.hDevMode != NULL) 
        GlobalFree(pdx.hDevMode); 

    if (pdx.hDevNames != NULL) 
        GlobalFree(pdx.hDevNames); 

    if (pdx.lpPageRanges != NULL)
        GlobalFree(pPageRanges);

    if (pdx.hDC != NULL) 
        DeleteDC(pdx.hDC);

    return hResult;
}
```

**To use this function, just launch it on button press/menu selection or whatever.**

The results in *XPS* seem consistent, but I get strange results in *MS OneNote 2007* which following images illustrate:

Font size is 14 :

[image]

Font size is 20 :

[image]

Font size is 20, but scaling from the above function was applied :

[image]

### END OF EDIT

### EDITED on July, 6th 2014:

The third picture from above edit was the result of `GDI` using **default height value** because the result of my mathematical adjustment  for font height was `0`. Once [zero is passed to CreateFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentioned behavior is expected.

After performing proper casting from `double` to `int` I got nearly perfect output -> last letter in the string **barely** exceeds the limit. I will continue to try improving this formula since I believe is promising. If anybody has another **mathematical** solution feel free to post it.

### END OF EDIT

*If further info / edit is required, leave a comment and I will react as soon as possible.*

Comment: Create a dummy font and get the length of a maximum length string. Don't throw it away if "it does not fit" -- use it to *calculate* a closer value! If the text is *n* pixels wide and your cell is *m* pixels, then scale the font size down to *m/n*.

Comment: @Jongware: Text did fit into the cell, but the result was not the one I expected. I use `DrawTextExt` to draw the test string, and test string has several words. Text must be vertically centered. Although the entire test string fits into the cell, vertical centering is not correct. If needed, I will update my post with small demo snippet. **Maybe I misunderstood you, or have applied your advice wrong.** Best regards.

Comment: It sounds as if I misinterpreted your explanation of "choosing proper font size so text of maximum length can fit into cell." I can see no reference to 'vertical centering' in your post, so maybe you should edit that in. (I'm also thinking, maybe a sketch or a screenshot of what you *have* would help.)

Comment: @Jongware: I believe you are right, but it is late at night now. Also, I would like to really put in an effort so my edit can be constructive, so I will make an update tomorrow ( screenshots included ). Best regards

Comment: @Jongware: I have edited my post per your instructions. As for vertical centering, I believe a simple math will help me out. Right now my main problem is displayed in last picture of my edit. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues involved.

The biggest problem I see is in this line:

```
lfHeight *= s.cy / ( rcText.bottom - rcText.top );
```

These are all integers.  In C and C++, division with integers results in truncation toward zero.  So if the result of the division "should" be 3.7, you'll end up with 3, which can be a pretty crude approximation.

Another problem is that GetTextExtentPoint32 does not wrap text, but DrawText does.  So you're measuring the text as though you're going to print it as a single line, and you actually draw it as multiple lines.  Instead of using GetTextExtendPoint32, you can measure the height with DrawText by DT_CALCRECT flag.

Putting these together, you want to measure your text like this:

```
WCHAR szText[] = L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги";
RECT rcText;
rcText.left = 0;
rcText.top = 0;
rcText.right = pageWidth / 4;
rcText.bottom = top;
const DWORD options = DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOCLIP;
DrawTextEx( pdx.hDC, szText, -1, &rcText,  options | DT_CALCRECT, NULL);

// Because we used DT_CALCRECT, the DrawTextEx call didn't draw anything,
// but it did adjust the bottom of rcText to account for the actual height.
double actual_height = static_cast<double>(rcText.bottom - rcText.top);
double desired_height = pageHeight / 10.0;
double ratio = desired_heigth / actual_height;

// Scale the font height by the ratio, and round it off to the nearest int.
lf.lfHeight = static_cast<int>(lf.lfHeight * ratio + 0.5);
```

Comment: I have tried your code and the result is not the one I needed to get. Unfortunately, `DrawTextExt` ( and `DrawText` too ) expand the rectangle width when length of the text is greater than the rectangle width ( see the docs for `DT_CALCRECT` ): [*If the largest word is wider than the rectangle, the width is expanded.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Although text is positioned nicely, regarding its height, it exceeds the original rectangle width. In my case I must keep rectangle width constant. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Then you'll need an iterative solution that keeps trying until it gets a good fit.  You can detect when DrawText with DT_CALCRECT widens the rectangle, and then you know you have to choose a smaller font size and try again.

Comment: Sadly, the whole point of my post was to dodge the iteration and use mathematic formula to do the job :(

Comment: I don't think you can rely on math alone because (1) GDI fonts don't scale linearly, (2) you're trying to fit both the horizontal and vertical dimensions, and (3) word wrap makes for a highly non-linear relationship between the horizontal and vertical.  I would do a binary search in font size space to find the largest size that still causes the text to fit.

Answer (score 3):

Okay. Basically, I start off with the suggested pointSize (14 in your code) and try to draw the text using the supplied bounding rect. If the text is too large, I go into an iterative loop that decreases the pointsize and measures again until the text will fit into the bounding rect.

If, on the other hand, the text is 'too small' I go into a loop that gradually increases it's size until it is too large. Once I reach this point, I decrease the point-size by 2 and return.

The reduction by 2 is a kludge or hack. I noticed that at times the size was reported as being equal to or smaller than the reported size of the bounding rect, yet still some characters would protrude past the edge of the bounding rect.

A better solution would make use of the DrawTextEx function to both calculate the size and draw the text. This would be better since you could make use of the iLeftmargin and iRightMargin members of the DRAWTEXTPARAMS struct that is passed to that function. Whether you wished to have a margin on each side, or simply wanted to add a single character's width, that you then halved when drawing the text would depend entirely on the desired outcome. I also added the DT_EXTERNALLEADING flag to obtain a small margin above/below the text, though there isn't one for vertical padding, so you'd have to make use of the margin attributes I mention.

Since the DT_VCENTER flag doesn't work with multi-line text, you'd also need to vertically offset the text yourself if you wished it to be vertically centered. You'd just have to offset the rect used for actually drawing the text by half of the difference between the area bounding rect's height and the text bounding rect's height.

I could have used a function like this for a few projects, so thanks for the impetus to actually exercise the grey matter and work it out!

Lastly, I used an interactive demo - one that responded to the WM_PAINT message of a (empty) dialog box. Since a HDC can be treated more-or-less the same whether it be for a printer or the screen, it provided a much quicker way of investigating the result.

**Output when plugged into your code:** (via cutePDF virtual printer)
[image]

**Code:**

```
int rectWidth(RECT &r)
{
    return (r.right - r.left) + 1;
}

int rectHeight(RECT &r)
{
    return (r.bottom - r.top) + 1;
}

void measureFunc(int pointSize, HDC hdc, RECT &pRectBounding, WCHAR *textToDraw, WCHAR *fontFaceName, int &resultWidth, int &resultHeight)
{
    int pixelsPerInchY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
    int logHeight = -MulDiv(pointSize, pixelsPerInchY, 72);
    RECT tmpRect = pRectBounding;
    HFONT old, tmp = CreateFont( logHeight, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, fontFaceName );
    old = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, tmp);
    DrawText(hdc, textToDraw, -1, &tmpRect, DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOCLIP | DT_CALCRECT| DT_EXTERNALLEADING  );
    SelectObject(hdc, old);
    DeleteObject(tmp);
    resultWidth = rectWidth(tmpRect);
    resultHeight = rectHeight(tmpRect);
}

HFONT getMaxFont(HDC hdc, WCHAR *fontName, WCHAR *textToDraw, RECT boundingRect)
{
    int maxWidth = rectWidth(boundingRect), maxHeight = rectHeight(boundingRect);
    int curWidth, curHeight, pointSize=14;

    measureFunc(pointSize, hdc, boundingRect, textToDraw, fontName, curWidth, curHeight);

    if ( (curWidth>maxWidth) || (curHeight>maxHeight) )
    {
        bool tooLarge = true;
        while (tooLarge)
        {
            pointSize--;
            measureFunc(pointSize, hdc, boundingRect, textToDraw, fontName, curWidth, curHeight);

            if ((curWidth>maxWidth)||(curHeight>maxHeight))
                tooLarge = true;
            else
                tooLarge = false;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        bool tooSmall = true;
        while (tooSmall)
        {
            pointSize++;
            measureFunc(pointSize, hdc, boundingRect, textToDraw, fontName, curWidth, curHeight);
            if ( (curWidth<maxWidth) && (curHeight<maxHeight) )
                tooSmall = true;
            else
                tooSmall = false;
        }
        if ((curWidth>maxWidth) || (curHeight>maxHeight))
        {
            pointSize-=2;
        }
    }

    int pixelsPerInchY = GetDeviceCaps( hdc, LOGPIXELSY );
    int curFontSize;
    HFONT result;
    curFontSize = -MulDiv(pointSize, pixelsPerInchY, 72);
    result = CreateFont(curFontSize, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, fontName );

    return result;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_SIZE:
        InvalidateRect(hwndDlg, NULL, true);
        return 0;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        {
            RECT mRect;
            GetClientRect(hwndDlg, &mRect);
            HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
            FillRect((HDC)wParam, &mRect, redBrush);
            DeleteObject(redBrush);
        }
        return true;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HFONT requiredFont, oldFont;
            WCHAR *textToDraw = L"Хидрогеотермална енергија Хидрогеотермална енерги";
            WCHAR *fontFace = L"Microsoft Sans Serif";
            RECT boundingRect, dlgRect;

            hdc = BeginPaint(hwndDlg, &ps);
                oldFont = (HFONT)GetCurrentObject(hdc, OBJ_FONT);

                GetClientRect(hwndDlg, &dlgRect);
                SetRect(&boundingRect, 0,0, rectWidth(dlgRect) / 4, rectHeight(dlgRect) / 10);
                FillRect(hdc, &boundingRect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

                requiredFont = getMaxFont(hdc, fontFace, textToDraw, boundingRect);
                SelectObject(hdc, requiredFont);
                SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
                DrawText(hdc, textToDraw, -1, &boundingRect, DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_NOCLIP | DT_EXTERNALLEADING  );

                SelectObject(hdc, oldFont);
                DeleteObject(requiredFont);

            EndPaint(hwndDlg, &ps);
        }
        return false;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am surprised no one ever came to this idea before! I was looking for mathematical formula that would substitute iterative solution, but it seems this is impossible... I will try to post this on *MathOverflow* just to "give it one last try" ( fortune smiles upon those who endure in their persistence! ). +1

Comment: No problem. I suspect that if your requirements were to paint a single-line string, that a calculated approach would work, though when the need to break text at line breaks comes into the picture that you wont be able to simply scale by desiredSize/resultSize. :)

Comment: I have tried your code for various paper sizes and orientations ( landscape/portrait ) and it seems that everything works fine. I will still keep "fighting" to find a mathematical solution for awhile before officially accept. Once bounty period expires I will award you the points ( unless better solution crops up ). I really thought that this will be easy but it turned out to be so hard...

Comment: Cool. :) - "I really thought that this will be easy" = famous last words. :p

Comment: Mathematical formula that was suggested on *MathOverflow* failed in one case by slightly exceeding the horizontal limit. I was planning to draw a table with data from database. I think that this problem will become even more complex than simply using approach of making the string of "maximum length" -> "calculate" font size -> do the drawing. Too many options fear me ( like kerning pairs, leading and other non-linear stuff ). I am tempted to ask another question but don't even know what I am looking for... "I really thought that this will be easy" -> no, it isn't -> it's a pain in the *ss!